# how to get src value from normal Text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what is the best way to get src value from normal text without instantiation dom Object in javascript . below is the code what I had tried . please suggest what I am missing

```js
function validate() {
  var test = document.getElementById("iframe_url").value;
  alert("==>" + test)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="iframe_url" name="iframe_url" value="<iframe   width='420' height='315'    src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k'></iframe>" />
<button id="opener" onclick="validate()">Open Dialog</button>
```

Comment: That's what. suppose if it has then how do we get that ? can you suggest . the scenario is if user pass direct src value then it's fine . else if user pass full iframe on text field I have to get src value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split text value using `src=` and then again split by either space or `>` to identify new attribute or close tag

#### Code

```js
function validate() {
  var test = document.getElementById("iframe_url").value;
  var src = test.split('src=')[1].split(/[ >]/)[0]
  alert("==>" + src)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="iframe_url" name="iframe_url" value="<iframe   width='420' height='315'    src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k'></iframe>" />
<button id="opener" onclick="validate()">Open Dialog</button>
```

#### Explanation

Test has following string

```
 <iframe width='420' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k'></iframe>
```

Now `string.split` takes a string or  regex to split the associated string. In our case first we provide string(`src=`) to it. This will divide string in following manner

```
["<iframe width='420' height='315'", "'https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k'></iframe>"]
```

We can discard 1st entry as we just want its value. So we select second entry and again split it using regex.

```js
string = "'https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k'></iframe>"
split value = [
  "'https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k'",
  "</iframe>"
]
```

The first value is the value we need.

Comment: Thanks it's working fine . can you elaborate something for split operation ?

Comment: @user7192787 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Thanks a lot for sharing the url

Comment: @Rajesh: Thanks a lot Rajesh  :)

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the `src` attribute from the HTML text you could use jQuery to convert it to an Element and then read the `src` property from it:

```js
$('#opener').click(function() {
  var $test = $($("#iframe_url").val());
  var src = $test.filter(':first').prop('src');
  console.log(src);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="iframe_url" name="iframe_url" value="<iframe   width='420' height='315'    src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k'></iframe>" />
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

Alternatively you could use a regular expression:

```js
$('#opener').click(function() {
  var test = $("#iframe_url").val();
  var src = /src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/gi.exec(test)[1];
  console.log(src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="iframe_url" name="iframe_url" value="<iframe   width='420' height='315'    src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k'></iframe>" />
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

However, I would suggest that you be very wary about executing any HTML/JS that you are letting your users enter in to the site as you could be leaving yourself wide open to injection and XSS attacks.

Comment: *without instantiation dom Object* I guess this will create an element. We are not adding to DOM is other thing

Comment: That's right. The entity is still an Element object whether it's in memory or attached to the DOM. I'll clear up the text to remove confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If allowed by cross-domain checks, try `window.frameElement.src` .

Otherwise, you are out of luck and left alone with `location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

you can get source value by just passing text value as an arguments.

```js
function validate(text) {
  var fsrc = text.split('src=')[1].split('><')[0];
  alert("=" + fsrc )
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="iframe_url" name="iframe_url" value="<iframe   width='420' height='315'    src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k'></iframe>" />
<button id="opener" onclick="validate(this.previousSibling.previousSibling.value)">Open Dialog</button>
```